# why delay() or queue() jquery doesn't work for me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to learn Jquery with exercice, and I have problem with delay in Jquery.

I want to make a pencil with my mouse, when I am on a div, I want it change color : yellow, after 500ms red, after 500ms return black.
Only the first part work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.case').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow").delay(500).queue(function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "red").delay(500).queue(function(){
                $(this).css("background-color", "#000");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <?php
        $i = 0;
        for ($i == 0; $i<50; $i++){
            $j = 0;
            for ($j == 0; $j<50; $j++){
                echo '<div class="case"></div>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

This is my code to make a lot of little div in my page

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrap{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(50, calc(100% / 50));
    grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.case{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
```

This is my css code.

Comment: "How X doesn't work for me" isn't a good question. Maybe "How to use X properly"

Comment: If I recall correctly, `delay()` is only for use with queued events. It cannot be used with synchronous code such as CSS changes like you have.

Comment: `css` isn't an animation function in jQuery. Only animation functions participate in the animation queue that `delay` and `queue` use. (It's unfortunate that [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) doesn't make that clearer, although it does say it only delays things "in the queue.")